# Mutagen in DDEV Making Craft CMS Slow to Propagate

Tags: craft4, ddev

This is related to [a previous question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/40555/changes-to-twig-template-take-over-20s-to-propagate).

When I have mutagen enabled in DDEV, it takes around 20 seconds for any changes to propagate. Even things as simple as updating a few lines of text in a twig file take this long.

**Example:**

Update _entry.twig (make a small update to {{ entry.title }}, changing it to {{ entry.postDate | date('d M Y') }})

```
{% extends "_layout.twig" %}

{% block content %}
 <h1 class="text-4xl text-black font-display my-4">{{entry.title }}</h1>

 <time class="text-sm block pb-4" datetime="{{ entry.postDate | date('Y-m-d') }}">{{ 
entry.postDate | date('d M Y') }}</time>
{% endblock %}
```

Changed to:

```
{% extends "_layout.twig" %}

{% block content %}
 <h1 class="text-4xl text-black font-display my-4">{{ entry.postDate | date('Y-m-d') }}</h1>

 <time class="text-sm block pb-4" datetime="{{ entry.postDate | date('Y-m-d') }}">{{ 
entry.postDate | date('d M Y') }}</time>
{% endblock %}
```

Takes over 20 seconds to be recognized.

Is there a way to speed up mutagen when used in a DDEV context with Craft CMS?

I don't want to disable mutagen because then everything in the control panel takes over 10 seconds to load.

Answer (score 1):

Mutagen should not be used when using WSL2.

The issue for the slow load was that the files were stored outside of the WSL2 filesystem.

Everything loads like lightning now.